# Finding closer date to a particular date

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have table Table1 :

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Customer] int, [RequestDt] int, [ClosedDt] int, [AppId] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Customer], [RequestDt], [ClosedDt], [AppId] )
VALUES
    (1, 201401, 201403, 1),
    (1, 201403, NULL, 2),
    (1, 201404, NULL, 3),
    (2, 201402, 201404, 4),
    (2, 201405, NULL, 5),
    (2, 201409, NULL, 6),
    (3, 201403, NULL, 7)
;
```

And i want to select which customers has AppID with closeDt and then had a new appid with requestDt bigger then CloseDt.

I did that using this:

> select * from Table1 t
>
> join old o on t.customer = o.customer
>
> and t.appId <> o.appid
>
> and t.requestDt > o.closeddt

But this will return me :

```
CUSTOMER    REQUESTDT   CLOSEDDT    APPID
1            201404      (null)       
2            201405      (null)       
2            201409      (null)
```

That is basically correct, but when the customer has two more appId with RequestDt after CloseDt i want to select only the one with closer RequestDt to CloseDt...I dont know how to do that.. :(

The result should be like this:

```
CUSTOMER    REQUESTDT   CLOSEDDT    APPID
1            201404      (null)       
2            201405      (null)
```

Hope its clear :)
Thank you!

Comment: I would highly recommend using the date datatype to store dates instead of ints. Help me undersand the logic here. Why are you expecting APPID 3 and 5? Is it the next RequestDt greater than ClosedDt?

Comment: Sorry , im not expecting id 3 and 5 , question corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the AppId then adding the`min()`function to your your original query should be enough:

```
select t.Customer, min(t.RequestDt) Requestdt, t.ClosedDt, null as Appid 
from Table1 t
join old o on t.customer = o.customer
and t.appId <> o.appid
and t.requestDt > o.closeddt
group by t.Customer, t.ClosedDt
```

Before you edited the question it included AppId too, and the queries below will give you that:

```
select 
    t2.customer, 
    t2.requestdt,
    t2.closeddt,
    t2.appid
from table1 t1
outer apply (     
    select top 1 * 
    from Table1 
    where RequestDt > t1.closeddt and Customer = t1.Customer
    ) t2
where t1.closeddt is not null
```

I'm almost certain sure there are better ways to do this, but my brain just won't work at the moment ;)

This should also work if the Appid is ordered:

```
select 
    t2.Customer, 
    RequestDt = min(t2.RequestDt), 
    ClosedDt  = min(t2.ClosedDt), 
    Appid     = min(t2.AppId) 
from Table1 t1
left join Table1 t2 on t1.Customer = t2.Customer and t1.ClosedDt < t2.RequestDt
where t1.ClosedDt is not null
group by t2.Customer
```

The queries above gives the following output:

```
Query 1:
Customer    Requestdt   ClosedDt    Appid
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           201404      NULL        NULL
2           201405      NULL        NULL

Query 2:
customer    requestdt   closeddt    appid
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           201404      NULL        3
2           201405      NULL        5    

Query 3:
Customer    RequestDt   ClosedDt    appid
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           201404      NULL        3
2           201405      NULL        5
```